# Company and shell-mode path completion

Tags: company-mode

When using company in shell-mode, a space is added after a match is made. This makes path completions behave badly, since I simply can't continue with the next directory but have to go back. I guess this behaviour is due to that when completing a command, you want the extra space.

I assume someone has already solved this, in order to get the usual path completion behaviour, but still use company in shell-mode.

(If my description was unclear, say I want to list `/some_directory/another_direcory/file.txt`. I type `ls /some`. I can now select `/some_directory/` as completion. Now I have `ls /some_directory/`  (node trailing space). I have to press backspace in order continue with `another_directory`.)

I've tried with emacs -Q and then enabled global-company-mode. The shell I get from M-x shell gives the same behaviour.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this behaviour, could you try with bare emacs (emacs -Q) with only company mode loaded?

Comment: @IqbalAnsari: I get the same behaviour with emacs -Q.

Comment: This *used* to happen to me. I'm not sure what fixed it. Maybe try updating company?

Comment: @nanny: I just enabled it last week, it's version 0.8.7.

Comment: @MeaningfulUsername Mine is 0.8.8-cvs. I'm not sure if it'll make a difference, but I guess it wouldn't hurt to try using the latest.

Comment: @nanny It will. This issue had been reported and fixed ~6 weeks ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Dmitry, it was a bug. With version 0.8.8 from Elpa it works as expected.